# VBA code:Save the fillter data to txt file

Tags: vba

VBA code: help me with, I want to save the fillter data to txt file.

```
Sub Intemp()

Dim arr, i As Long
Dim FPath As String

FPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "text" & ".txt"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
arr = Sheet5.Range("B1:C" & [B100000].End(xlUp).Row)

Open FPath For Output As #1
For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    Print #1, arr(i, 1) & vbTab & arr(i, 2)
Next i

Close #1
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you would like to do. Can you please show your starting point and desired end point?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign your filtered values to an array, an easy way to do that would be to use advanced filtering and filter into another area of the worksheet and assign your values there.

But a simple approach that will get you started is to just loop your rows in your range, if the row is hidden, then move on - otherwise, print the data to your text document.

```
Dim rng As Range, r As Long
Set rng = Sheet5.Range("B1:C" & [B100000].End(xlUp).Row)

Dim FPath As String
FPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "text" & ".txt"
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Open FPath For Output As #1
With Sheet5
    For r = rng.Row To rng.Rows.Count + rng.Row - 1
        If Not .Rows(r).Hidden Then
            Print #1, .Cells(r, 1) & vbTab & .Cells(r, 2)
        End If
    Next
End With

Close #1
```